# How to estimate the range

Tags: analysis

Can someone help me to estimate the range of $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, I can't do that.Thanks

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n\sqrt{n}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)$ is defined as an absolutely convergent series of continuous, non-negative and increasing functions, so $f(x)$ ranges from $f(0)=0$ to $f(1)=\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$. For any $x\in(-1,0)$ we have
$$ f'(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (-x)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}} $$
and the RHS is positive by the alternating series test. Once you prove that
$$ \lim_{x\to -1^+} f(x) = f(-1) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1\right)\,\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) $$
you have that $f(x)$ is increasing on $[-1,1]$, hence its range is given by
$$ \left[\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1\right)\,\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right),\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right]\approx \left[-0.765147, 2.6123753\right].$$
As an alternative way, you may prove that $f(x)$ has the following integral representation:
$$ f(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{s}}{e^s-x}\,ds $$
and that $f$ is increasing on $(-1,1)$ by differentiating such integral representation.
It also provides an analytic continuation of $f(x)$ to the region $x<-1$.